# Inconsistent session in Wordpress + WooCommerce after redirect back from Paypal

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I have a wordpress store with woocommerce which has paypal payments enabled.

I'm developing a plugin that collects some data from the client on the cart page, stores that data in woocommerce session. Then client goes to paypal to pay, then after a successful payment gets redirected back to the site to the order confirmation page where my plugin is supposed to perform additional tasks.

This works well on my test site when I access it from my computer. It does not however work for me when I try it from my android phone.

The session "seems" to be lost when I come back from Paypal and none of the data is accessible through Woocommerce's WC()->session->get

Interestingly, the data is still there in the sessions table in the database, it just doesn't get loaded when I get redirected from Paypal.

In order to try to debug this, I wrote 2 lines of code in index.php where I'm writing to log the Cookie header every time the site is loaded. I can see the cookie data being logged when I navigate around the site.

However when the navigation back from paypal happens, the Cookie header is empty, so no wonder the session doesn't get loaded.

My question is, what can I do about it so that I can access the data after I get redirected back to the site.

PS - the trickiest part is that the issue is intermittent. I managed to find a laptop with a browser which behaved exactly as my android phone so I could inspect the issue easier, but after doing a couple of tests, it started being able to access the session data when navigating back from paypal to the site. So basically now "it's working" and I can't reproduce the issue again even after clearing all site data from the browser. But I know the issue still occurs for some people, outside my office.

Answer (score 0):

I won't pretend to be an expert on third party cookie session preservation, but the bottom line is browsers are being more and more aggressive about dropping cookies when navigating away and back to a site, and so you shouldn't rely on this type of session preservation if the data you are saving is important.

The newest WooCommerce PayPal module uses the Express Checkout API, which generates an EC-################# before redirecting the user away, and you'll have this in the URL when they return from PayPal. So you can use this to keep track of the same user returning. But it also has support for Smart Payment Buttons so your site stays loaded in the background, which is a better experience anyway.